# "Scrape" Web Page Output to PHP for Subsequent Parsing Rather Than Rendering Web Page to Screen

Tags: php, file, parsing, screen

I want to be able to capture a web page for further processing in PHP rather than having the page displayed on screen.

Is there a way to do that?

**Specifically**

I want to take the results of this URL and parse it in PHP

http://rpc.geocoder.us/service/namedcsv?zip=20502

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Now I'm second guessing myself.. Your title and explanation seem to be very different. Are you trying to scrape the content from that link? Or capture your own output before its sent to the screen?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I will reread my question and clear it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use file_get_contents().

```
$web_page_as_string = file_get_contents('http://rpc.geocoder.us/service/namedcsv?zip=20502');
do_magic($web_page_as_string);
```